# Python 2.6 send connection object over Queue / Pipe / etc

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pipe, pickle

Given [this bug (Python Issue 4892)](http://bugs.python.org/issue4892) that gives rise to the following error:

```
>>> import multiprocessing
>>> multiprocessing.allow_connection_pickling()
>>> q = multiprocessing.Queue()
>>> p = multiprocessing.Pipe()
>>> q.put(p)
>>> q.get()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/.../python2.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 91, in get
    res = self._recv()
TypeError: Required argument 'handle' (pos 1) not found
```

Does anyone know of a workaround to pass a Connection object on a Queue?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

(What I believe is) A better method, after some playing around (I was having the same problem. Wanted to pass a pipe through a pipe.) before discovering this post:

```
>>> from multiprocessing import Pipe, reduction
>>> i, o = Pipe()
>>> reduced = reduction.reduce_connection(i)
>>> newi = reduced[0](*reduced[1])
>>> newi.send("hi")
>>> o.recv()
'hi'
```

I'm not entirely sure why this is built this way (someone would need insight into what the heck the reduction part of multiprocessing is about for that) but it does definitely work, and requires no pickle import. Other than that, it's pretty close to the above in what it does, but simpler. I also threw this into the python bug report so others know of the workaround.

Comment: Great answer. Definitely looks to be a better option.

Comment: This is a good answer, and working for me in 2.6. However, in 2.7, when the function `reduction.rebuild_connection` AKA `reduced[0]` is called, the thread blocks indefinitely.

Comment: I'm having the same problem as @SamMagura. Does anyone know of a workaround for Python 2.7?

Comment: To make it work with windows, when rebuilding the reduced pipe use `from multiprocessing.reduction import rebuild_pipe_connection` instead of the `reduced[0]`. (Tested with Win7 & python 2.7.5). See http://bugs.python.org/msg157736

Answer (score 8):

Here's roughly what I did:

```
# Producer
from multiprocessing.reduction import reduce_connection
from multiprocessing import Pipe

   # Producer and Consumer share the Queue we call queue
def handle(queue):
   reader, writer = Pipe()
   pickled_writer = pickle.dumps(reduce_connection(writer))
   queue.put(pickled_writer)
```

and

```
# Consumer
from multiprocessing.reduction import rebuild_connection

def wait_for_request():
    pickled_write = queue.get(block=True) # block=True isn't necessary, of course
    upw = pickle.loads(pickled_writer) # unpickled writer
    writer = upw[0](upw[1][0],upw[1][1],upw[1][2])
```

The last line is cryptic, coming from the following:

```
>>> upw
(<function rebuild_connection at 0x1005df140>,
(('/var/folders/.../pymp-VhT3wX/listener-FKMB0W',
17, False), True, True))
```

Hope that helps someone else. It works fine for me.